kpartx does not work as expected inside docker container
I am trying to create disk image inside docker container.
I run the following commands:
Run container with debian
$ sudo docker run --privileged --rm -it debian

Update apt and install packages
# apt update
# apt install fdisk kpartx

Create disk image filled with zeros
# dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=100M count=10 status=progress

Make GPT and two partitions (ESP and linux)
# echo -e ',200M,U\n,+\n' | sfdisk -X gpt disk.img

Create partition in the device mapper with the help of kpartx
# kpartx -av disk.img

add map loop0p1 (254:0): 0 409600 linear 7:0 2048
add map loop0p2 (254:1): 0 1634304 linear 7:0 411648

Remove paritions from the device mapper
# kpartx -dv disk.img

But kpartx -dv disk.img do not remove partitions from the device device mapper, but
# kpartx -dv /dev/loop0

del devmap : loop0p1
del devmap : loop0p2 

does.
What I am doing wrong?
If I do the same things in Linux (not in Docker container) kpartx -dv disk.img works as expected.
I observe incorrect behaviour in Linux and macOS docker engines.
